# bash script: printLine() function not being called in main

Tags: bash, shell, loops

My overall goal is to output an 8x8 checkerboard pattern to the terminal screen. I have a recursive function I've written, to print one 8x1 row of the checkerboard starting with a black or white tile depending on whether I call the script from the terminal with an option flag or not. This function is called printLine() and I believe it works perfectly. However, when I call it in my loops in main(), it is only executed once, and then the program continues to run as if waiting for user input.

Like I said, I'm pretty confident in printLine(), and I'm also confident that the loops in main() works, as I've replaced the printLine() function call with a simple echo "hi" statement, and it prints "hi"as many times as the loop specifies when I run the script, so I'm not sure why the loops don't call printLine() iteratively when their bodies consist of it rather than the simple echo statement. There's some unused constants I haven't used yet just for testing purposes, so please ignore those.

```
# Script 1 - Checkerboard 
# 
# Name: xxx  
# PID: xxx  
# Account: xxx  

# ============================== DO NOT CHANGE ============================== #

# Constants used
TILE_BLACK="\033[0;40m  \033[0;0m"    # DO NOT CHANGE
TILE_WHITE="\033[0;47m  \033[0;0m"    # DO NOT CHANGE
SQUARES_PER_LINE=8                    # DO NOT CHANGE
HALF_DIVISOR=2                        # DO NOT CHANGE
NUM_ITERATIONS=4                      # DO NOT CHANGE
ERR="\tERROR: Invalid flag given.\n"  # DO NOT CHANGE
USAGE="USAGE: ./checkerboard.sh [-r]" # DO NOT CHANGE

rotate_flag="f"

# Parse command line arguments
while getopts ":r" arg $@; do
  case $arg in

    # rotation wanted
    r) rotate_flag="t";;

    # Invalid flag provided
   \?) echo; echo -e "$ERR"; echo "$USAGE"; exit 1;;

  esac
done

# Remove parsed option flags
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

# ========================= YOUR CODE STARTS BELOW ========================= #

# FIXME: Write a function that prints one row of the checkerboard. It should
# look at the argument passed in to determine if it will start by printing a
# white or black square. This is an optional method, but will help you
# implement the main method.
count=0;
function printLine() { # One way to define a function
    until [ "$count" == 8 ]; do
    if  [ "$1" ==  "$TILE_WHITE" ]; then
    echo -en "$TILE_WHITE "
    count=$(($count + 1))
    printLine "$TILE_BLACK"
  elif [ "$1" == "$TILE_BLACK" ]; then       
    echo -en "$TILE_BLACK"
    count=$(($count + 1))
    printLine "$TILE_WHITE"
  fi
  done
}

function main() { # Another way to define a function

  counter=0

  if [ $rotate_flag == "t" ]; then
    # This line creates a loop that will run NUM_ITERATIONS times
    #while (!cond)
    until [ "$counter" == 4 ]; do

      # FIXME: Use the print functions to draw two REVERSED rows of the board
      count2=0;
      until [ "$count2" == 2 ]; do
         printLine "$TILE_BLACK"
         printLine "$TILE_WHITE"
         count2=$(($count2 + 1))
      done
      counter=$(($counter + 1))
   done

  else
    until [ $counter -eq $NUM_ITERATIONS ]; do
      # FIXME: Use the print functions to draw two rows of the board
      count3=0;
      until [ "$count2" == 2 ]; do
         printLine "$TILE_BLACK"
         printLine "$TILE_WHITE"
         count3=$(($count3 + 1))
      done
      counter=$(($counter + 1))
    done
  fi
}

# ============================== DO NOT CHANGE ============================== #
main # Calls the main function to start the script up
exit 0
```

Comment: Why do you think `printLine` is not being called?

Comment: It is being called, but it is only being called once. I want it to be called as many times as the loop is iterating.

Comment: OK, why do you think `printLine` is only being called once?

Comment: I am updating the count variable in accordance with the loop condition, so I am not entirely sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printLine` increments a variable `count` but this is never reset.

So once `$count == 8`, the `until` loop does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
count3=0;
until [ "$count2" == 2 ]; do
    printLine "$TILE_BLACK"
    printLine "$TILE_WHITE"
    count3=$(($count3 + 1))
done
```

Here is a dead loop. You check `count2` for loop ending condition, but just updates `count3`. Fix it.

Comment: @CSmizzle learn to debug: run bash script with `-x` parameter, for example `bash -x ./checkerboard.sh`.

Comment: Thank you for being so kind. With the help and the tip. I'll get familiar with the debugger and form a habit of it. Really appreciate the help!